# How do I express this with a RewriteCond?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect users to an error page if they enter any URL **not starting** with 'en' or 'fr'. I cannot figure out how to express this as a RewriteCond / RewriteRule.

To be clearer, some examples:

```
http://mysite.com/en/foo/ ==> Cool, do nothing
http://mysite.com/fr/foo/ ==> Cool, do nothing

http://mysite.com/foo/ ==> ERROR, redirect to /404/index.php    
http://mysite.com/blah/foo/ ==> ERROR, redirect to /404/index.php
```

I'm sure it must be pretty simple but I could not find this specific scenario addressed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^/(?!en|fr).*
```

This regex should match any path which doesn't begin with `/en` or `/fr`. The `(?!expression)` syntax is a negative lookahead; it matches a *position* where the contained expression doesn't start matching.

Comment: Holy smokes, that was fast! Thanks Dav. Would you be so kind as to write the complete RewriteRule instruction for me? As I'm a newbie, I'm not sure where that would go... Cheers!